# Combining 3 node sever into 1 node server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 3 node server named:

dishServer.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    assert = require('assert');    
var Dishes = require('./models/dishes');    
// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/conFusion';mongoose.connect(url);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
    // we're connected!
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");    
    // create a new dish
    Dishes.create({
      "name": "Uthapizza",

      "description": "A unique . . .",
      "comments": [
        {
          "rating": 5,
          "comment": "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
          "author": "John Lemon"
        },

      ]
}, function (err, dish) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Dish created!');
        console.log(dish);    
        var id = dish._id;    
        // get all the dishes
        setTimeout(function () {
            Dishes.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
                    $set: {
                        description: 'Updated Test'
                    }
                }, {
                    new: true
                })
                .exec(function (err, dish) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('Updated Dish!');
                    console.log(dish);    
                    dish.comments.push({
                        rating: 5,
                        comment: 'I\'m getting a sinking feeling!',
                        author: 'Leonardo di Carpaccio'
                    });

                    dish.save(function (err, dish) {
                        console.log('Updated Comments!');
                        console.log(dish);

                        db.collection('dishes').drop(function () {
                            db.close();
                        });
                    });
                });
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

leaderServer.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    assert = require('assert');

var Leaders = require('./models/leadership');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/conFusion';mongoose.connect(url);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
    // we're connected!
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");

    // create a new leader
    Leaders.create({
      "name": "Peter Pan",

      "description": "Our CEO, Peter, . . ."
}, function (err, leader) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Leaders created!');
        console.log(leader);

        var id = leader._id;

        // get all promotion dishes
        setTimeout(function () {
            Leaders.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
                    $set: {
                        description: 'Updated Test'
                    }
                }, {
                    new: true
                })
                .exec(function (err, leader) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('Updated Leader!');
                    console.log(leader);


                    db.collection('leaders').drop(function () {
                            db.close();
                        });
                });
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

promoServer.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    assert = require('assert');

var Promotions = require('./models/promotions');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/conFusion';mongoose.connect(url);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
    // we're connected!
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");

    // create a new promotion
    Promotions.create({
      "name": "Weekend Grand Buffet",

      "description": "Featuring . . ."
}, function (err, promotion) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Promotions created!');
        console.log(promotion);    
        var id = promotion._id;    
        // get all promotion dishes
        setTimeout(function () {
            Promotions.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
                    $set: {
                        description: 'Updated Test'
                    }
                }, {
                    new: true
                })
                .exec(function (err, promotion) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('Updated Promotion!');
                    console.log(promotion);


                    db.collection('promotions').drop(function () {
                            db.close();
                        });
                });
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

Is there any way to combine them into one node server referencing these three servers?
I found ways to make a node server with referencing three models: dishes, leaderships, promotions. But can't combine these three servers into one.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to perform DB operations against a single database, each involving logic of distinct collections. You can connect to Mongo once and use any code workflow control dependency, like `async` or practice, like using `Promise` to do what you want.

It's not *a server* what you need, but to perform distinct operations in one single go. I mean, it's not like you're setting up a web server to provide an API against a remote DB, from your code it seems they're particular db "operations" which u are performing.